# PHP - Most efficient way to update MySQL Text

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple CMS running PHP/MySQL and I'm looking for the most efficient way to update LONGTEXT fields across multiple tables when I change the title/url for a page.

For example:
I change the page "/contact" to "/contact-us" and I want any LONGTEXT fields across multiple tables containing

```
...<a href="/contact">...
```

to update to

```
...<a href="/contact-us>"...
```

I know I could just do a SELECT, match records and replace, but I'm thinking there has to be some method that's lighter on the MySQL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this:

```
UPDATE table SET some_column = REPLACE(some_column, 'href="/contact', 'href="/contact-us')
```

Which appears to do exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

run the following in order to find the entries that contain the string you want to change

```
mysqldump -u username db-name | grep "<a href=\"/contact\">"
```

and then go one-by-one and update the relevant entries.